# Can't connect to the Binance websocket with Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, binance

I'm using NodeJS and trying to connect to the Binance Websocket with Socket.io but it seems to not work, but when I try it with the standard "ws" library, it works fine and I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. [These are the docs](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md) if needed.

Here's my code with Socket.io

```js
const io = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade");

console.log("Starting...");

socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Connection Made!"); //This never fires
});
socket.on("message", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Here's my code with the "ws" library

```js
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade");

ws.on("message", function incoming(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Which works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

According to https://socket.io/docs/v4/#What-Socket-IO-is-not .

## What Socket.IO is not

Socket.IO is NOT a WebSocket implementation. Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket as a transport when possible, it adds additional metadata to each packet. That is why a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server, and a Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a plain WebSocket server either.

```
// WARNING: the client will NOT be able to connect!
const socket = io("ws://echo.websocket.org");
```

If you are looking for a plain WebSocket server, please take a look at ws or uWebSockets.js.

There are also talks to include a WebSocket server in the Node.js core.

On the client-side, you might be interested by the robust-websocket package.